# How to stop threads in an infinte loop by passing in a True or False variable?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, bots

I have been searching for days for a solution to this issue, if anyone can point me in the right direction, I will be so grateful.

I have been writing a program that allows a user to create multiple trading bots at the same time, each bot is created as an individual thread that makes an api call to Binance for the latest market data and evaluates this data with conditional statements and place trades accordingly. The code I am using for this has been trimmed to only the essential parts for simplicity.. I have a Bot class...

```
class Bot(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, symbol, time, exposure, strategy):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.symbol = symbol
    self.time = time
    self.exposure = exposure
    self.strategy = strategy
    self.stop_bot = False

def scanner(self):
    while self.stop_bot == False:
        client = Client(self.api_key, self.secret_key, {"verify": True, "timeout": 20})
        price_data = client.get_klines(symbol=self.symbol, interval=self.time_interval)
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(price_data)
        self.modified_df = pd.DataFrame(price_data)
        time.sleep(10)

def kill(self):
     self.stop_bot = True
```

And the Bot class is called from the bot manager terminal class...

```
class Bot_Manager:

    def __init__(self):

        self.bot_list = []
        bot = object

    def terminal(self):
        while True:
            user_input = input('(1) Create new Bot (2) Stop Bot')
            if user_input == '1':
                symbol = 'OMGUSDT'
                time = '1D'
                exposure = 1000
                strategy = 'SAR'
                bot_name = input('name your bot: ')
                bot = Bot(symbol=symbol, time=time, exposure=exposure, strategy=strategy, bot_name=bot_name)
                
                scanner_thread = threading.Thread(target=bot.scanner, daemon=True)
                scanner_thread.name = bot_name
                scanner_thread.start()
                self.bot_list.append(scanner_thread)

            elif user_input == '2':
                for thread in threading.enumerate():
                    print(thread.name)
                print(self.bot_list)

                user_input = input('Bot to stop: ')
                i = int(user_input)
                print(self.bot_list[i])
```

Now I am able to create multiple threads / bots by repeatedly selecting option 1. However the issue I am facing is stopping these threads when a user selects option 2. If for example I create 3 bots and name them Bot A, Bot B and Bot C.. when I enumerate this in a for loop, i get the following:

```
MainThread

Bot A

Bot B

Bot C
```

and when I store each thread into a list and print the list I see the following:

```
[<Thread(Bot A, started 8932)>, <Thread(Bot B, started 12268)>, <Thread(Bot C, started 13436)>]
```

I would like the user to be able to select the thread / bot they want to stop from the list, so in this example if the user types 1, it should return the thread `<Thread(Bot B, started 12268)>`and stop this thread by passing the variable `stop_bot = True`. However I haven't had much luck with this.

When I call the function `bot.kill()` it only stops the last thread that was created, so for this example, Bot C. When it runs again, it doesn't remove any other thread. Is there anyway to pass in the variable `stop_bot = True` on an already created object / thread? Or is there another method to this that I have overlooked... Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to this by adding multiple bots to a data frame and passing this into the bot class. 1 thread was created to iterate through the data frame and by removing rows of the data frame, the bots would be removed.